# Signal envelope

Tags: signal-detection, envelope, simulink

[image: Signal]

I have a relatively low-frequency signal and want to calculate the peak envelope of it in Simulink. I tried some of filters but the envelope is not well precise. can anyone help, how can I do it?

[image: Simulink diagram]

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "peak envelope"?

Comment: peak envelope is picking the peak values of a signal

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you explain what you did and what was the problem? Standard envelope detection (say, with a Hilbert transform) should work pretty well with the signal in your plot.

Comment: I used Hilbert transform, but the envelope has a bit higher amplitudes than signal itself, and also it has a delay, how can I fixed that?

Comment: The delay isn't a problem in your application, because your peak is just a single number. Anyway, the delay is just the group delay of your hilbert transform filter. Higher amplitudes might be correct, depending on your sampling instants. Without seeing your code and what your code does, no telling.

Comment: Muller, look at my simulink diagram, and also the delay in the envelope! shown above

Comment: You're not using the Hilbert transform in that diagram (but it should still work; it's a square-law detector). I think your low-pass filter does not have enough rejection; you can still see a bit of the carrier in the envelope.

Comment: What's the reason for using a decimator after the squaring? You could introduce aliases if you're not careful.

Comment: decimator is used for down sampling, do you think the problem of the delay is due to decimator?

Comment: What I mean is, why do you want to decimate the signal at that point? I would decimate after the low-pass filter. The delay is caused by both FIR filters, but you shouldn't worry about it -- it's unavoidable. If you want to align the signals at `Scope2` you should delay the modulated signal by the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

The best reference that I'm aware of on Complex Signal Envelopes detailing definitions, some difficulties and workarounds is:

Nuttall, Albert H. Complex envelope properties, interpretation, filtering, and evaluation. No. NUSC-TR-8827. NAVAL UNDERWATER SYSTEMS CENTER NEW LONDON CT, 1991.

available at:

http://www.dtic.mil/docs/citations/ADA234478